# Exception with ES query

Tags: elasticsearch, web-crawler, apache-storm, stormcrawler

i am using stormcrawler 1.16 with ELasticsearch-7.2.0. java version is 1.8.0_252 . storm version is 1.2.3, maven version is  3.6.3.

i have created project using mvn archetype -

```
    mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler - 
    DarchetypeArtifactId=storm-crawler-elasticsearch-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=LATEST
```

i made a seeds.txt file and put 9 urls only for testing and submitted the topology using the command given in REAEDME.md file in --remote mode.

it run successfully and crawl the pages as intented.

but problem arise when i put 8000 URLs in seeds.txt file.

i run ES_IndexInit.sh file again and submitt the topology using the same command as i previously did.
then i get this error -

```
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_252]
     2020-06-12 11:26:11.416 c.d.s.e.p.AggregationSpout pool-12-thread-1 [ERROR] [spout #1]  Exception with ES query
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:714) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvent(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:174) [stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:148) [stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:351) [stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:221) [stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64) [stormjar.jar:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_252]
```

then i look for errors in worker.log file. i found same error over there.
then i check health of my shards -

```
      {
   "cluster_name" : "my-cluster1",
  "status" : "green",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
   "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
   "active_primary_shards" : 2,
    "active_shards" : 2,
   "relocating_shards" : 0,
    "initializing_shards" : 0,
    "unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
   "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
   "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
    "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
    "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 100.0,
   "indices" : {
     ".kibana_task_manager" : {
      "status" : "green",
      "number_of_shards" : 1,
       "number_of_replicas" : 0,
      "active_primary_shards" : 1,
       "active_shards" : 1,
      "relocating_shards" : 0,
      "initializing_shards" : 0,
      "unassigned_shards" : 0,
     "shards" : {
       "0" : {
      "status" : "green",
      "primary_active" : true,
      "active_shards" : 1,
      "relocating_shards" : 0,
      "initializing_shards" : 0,
      "unassigned_shards" : 0
       }
      }
    },
      ".kibana_1" : {
  "status" : "green",
  "number_of_shards" : 1,
  "number_of_replicas" : 0,
  "active_primary_shards" : 1,
  "active_shards" : 1,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "shards" : {
    "0" : {
      "status" : "green",
      "primary_active" : true,
      "active_shards" : 1,
      "relocating_shards" : 0,
      "initializing_shards" : 0,
      "unassigned_shards" : 0
            }
           }
         }
      }
    }
```

shards's health is green.
now if i submit crawler topology in a different or new project, topology remains ideal and do not emitts or transffered any tuple.

am i using versions that are compatible with each other ? should i use java 11 for elasticsearch or it works fine ?

details about instance -
i am using ec2 medium intance ubuntu 18.04 with 4 gb memory.

someone please explain what the issue is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to run the ESInitScript again unless you want to delete the URLs that are in the status index. If you run it more than once, there will be nothing in status and this could be why the topology is idle.

There is no reason why having more URLs in the seeds file would cause a problem, we routinely have seed files with > 1M urls and this is not a problem.